# How can I produce a warning with ceberus if a key is missing?

Tags: python, validation, cerberus

Cerberus allows for [required](https://docs.python-cerberus.org/en/stable/validation-rules.html#required) fields but I'd like to have a "preferred" class of fields such that a warning message is logged if they're missing. Some ideas I have that don't seem great are the following:

1. I could extend the validator with a [custom rule](https://docs.python-cerberus.org/en/stable/customize.html#custom-rules), but these are called with `field` and `value` arguments, making me suspect that this function would be called on missing fields. [__validate_required_fields](https://github.com/pyeve/cerberus/blob/5c267b554a39b5a8650659d3eea0cf383e47a166/cerberus/base.py#L1755) which is called on the document to generate missing fileds would be more ideal, but I'm not sure how to hook that in.
2. Cerberus offers a [check_with](https://docs.python-cerberus.org/en/stable/validation-rules.html#check-with) option but again, I'm not sure if this would be called on missing fields.
3. I could try to mark these as required and do the tracing in an error handler. This is not ideal because validation should not fail if "preferred" fields are missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Your suspicion is correct, fields that are not in the document are not validated fully. And `__validate_required_fields` isn't designated to be overridden (name mangling would fail due to two leading `__`).
2. It is not as in 1.
3. That would best be done by overriding the `validate` method and post-process the various (!) error containers.

I think the simplest solution would be to validate against two different schemas, one that checks *hard* and one that you get the warnings from.